# facebook connect: redirect to white page with only the facebook logo on it (amazon ec2)

Tags: python, facebook, dns, tornado

I've got a godaddy .com domain and I am forwarding it to an elastic amazon ec2 instance IP. I've recently added Facebook connect to my website, but when a user presses the 'Facebook connect' button, the button just redirects to a blank page with only the Facebook logo on it. When I click the Facebook logo, it redirects to the Facebook app page that requests permissions from the user for my website.

The page looks something like this: http://img714.imageshack.us/img714/972/fbpage.png

In this facebook connect link, my redirect url is just the IP of my elastic amazon ec2 instance, and not the name/domain of my website (.com domain), which I actually want. Is this somehow related to godaddy <-> amazon ec2? Something with a DNS resolve? I couldn't find this problem on Google.

Comment: What is the actual HTML for the logo? It would also help to know the IP address and what your DNS settings are for the domain in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forward the domain. Depending on how you're doing your auth, you'll generally be passing/using an oauth callback url to facebook.

Get your "dynamic IP" on your ec2 machine:

```
curl www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp
```

Then setup an A record in DNS for your domain to point to the IP you get from this. If you're hosting something business critical, I'd recommend you purchase an "elastic IP" - but I haven't had my "dynamic" IP change on me since I signed up (5 months ago).